# How do I remove the blank lines from my java program output?

Tags: java

I am writing a program to display the results of a tic tac toe game. I am getting a blank line between each printed line when the program is run.

Here is my code:

```
public class TicTacToe {
    static void print(char[][] arr){

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            System.out.println();
            for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
                if(j!=arr[i].length-1)
                  System.out.print("|");
            }
            System.out.println();
            if(i!=arr[i].length-1)
                  System.out.println("_____");
        }
    }
    /**

     * @param args

     *****/ The tic tac toe results****
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("First Tic Tac Toe: ");
        char[][] ttt1 = {
             {'X','O','X'},
             {'0','O','X'},
             {'X','X','O'}};
           print(ttt1);

           System.out.print("Second Tic Tac Toe: ");
           char[][] ttt2 = {
             {'O','O','X'},
             {'0','O','X'},
             {'X','X','O'}};
           print(ttt2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you have 2 calls to `System.out.println();` in your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `System.out.println();` right before the if statement in your print function. If you get rid of it you shouldn't be getting any more blank lines

Comment: I almost wanted to suggest changing `System.out.println("_____");` to `print` instead after seeing how the `X|O|X` would be paste as trailing part after the informational `First/Second Tic Tac Toe: ` prints, but removing that first `System.out.println();` AND changing the prints for `First/Second Tic Tac Toe: ` to `println` would indeed be a better fix.

Answer (score 0):

i made minor changes

```java
public class TicTacToe {
    static void print(char[][] arr){

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

            for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
                if(j!=arr[i].length-1)
                    System.out.print("|");
            }
            System.out.println();
            if(i!=arr[i].length-1)
                System.out.println("-----");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("First Tic Tac Toe:");
        char[][] ttt1 = {
                {'X','O','X'},
                {'0','O','X'},
                {'X','X','O'}};
        print(ttt1);

        System.out.println("Second Tic Tac Toe: ");
        char[][] ttt2 = {
                {'O','O','X'},
                {'0','O','X'},
                {'X','X','O'}};
        print(ttt2);
    }
}
```